# Unable to add authorization header on axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I am facing a strange issue, that I my httpClient is not adding axios header. My `httpClient.js`

```
import axios from "axios";
import logHandler from "../utils/logService";

axios.defaults.headers.common['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
// axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = "Bearer "+ localStorage.getItem('_token');

let client = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://laracms.test/api'
});

axios.interceptors.response.use(null, (error) => {
    const expectedError =
        error.response &&
        error.response.status >= 400 &&
        error.response.status < 500;

    if (!expectedError) {
        logHandler.log(error);
    }

    return Promise.reject(error);
});

function setJwt(token) {
    console.log('called setJWt >>', token);
    axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = "Bearer "+ token;
}

export default {
    get: client.get,
    post: client.post,
    put: client.put,
    delete: client.delete,
    setJwt
};
```

and my `authService.js` looks as:

```
// import { apiURL } from "../config/config.json";
import httpClient from "../utils/httpClient";

 const apiURL = "http://laracms.test/api"

const apiEndpoint = apiURL + "/auth";
const tokenKey = "_token";

httpClient.setJwt(getJwt());

export async function register(user) {
    return httpClient.post(apiEndpoint + "/register", {
        name: user.name,
        email: user.email,
        password: user.password,
    });
}

export async function verify(activation_code) {
    return httpClient.get(apiEndpoint + "/verify-email/" + activation_code);
}

export async function login(email, password) {
    const response = await httpClient.post(apiEndpoint + "/login", {
        email,
        password,
    });
    const token = response.headers["x-auth-token"];
    localStorage.setItem(tokenKey, token);
    return response;
}

export function getCurrentUser() {
    try {
        const jwt = localStorage.getItem(tokenKey);
        return jwtDecode(jwt);
    } catch (ex) {
        return null;
    }
}

export function logout() {
    localStorage.removeItem(tokenKey);
}

export function getJwt() {
    if(tokenKey in localStorage){
        return localStorage.getItem(tokenKey);
    }
    return null;
}

export default {
    verify,
    login,
    logout,
    getCurrentUser,
    getJwt,
};
```

Although, i can clearly see that `setJwt` being called

[image]

However, if I uncomment the line just below `axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';` It is sending the authorization header too. Possibly, it shouldn't matter but just for the info I am using Laravel 8 as the backend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating an axios instance in `axios.create(...` and you are using that instance as your client, when you set the header for authorization you set it to "axios defaults" instead of your previously created instance. Add the header to the axios instance in your setJWT function and that should worl

Answer (score 0):

You are creating the client with the headers written on the top part of httpClient.js. So later on when you are adding another header to axios, it is getting added there, but not in the already created client.

You can try returning a newly created client from there after adding any header and use that, or as you are already using a response interceptor, you can try using a request interceptor and add your token there. Hope this solves your problem